# sqlalchemy core build dynamic query

Tags: python, curl, sqlalchemy

I need to build a search form based on the request form input using flask framework. The query should be dynamically built based on various input values of the parameters using sqlalchemy CORE ONLY. Some of the values can be null. Also need curl command for the same. I have come across sqlalchemy orm based approach using filter. How exactly should I approach? I tried the following:
table:

```
docs = Table("docs", metadata,   
                      Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column("file_name", String),
                      Column("custom_tag", String, nullable=True),
                      Column("description", String, nullable=True),
                      Column("up_date", DateTime(timezone=True),
                             default=datetime.datetime.utcnow),
                      Column("category_id", Integer, 
                             ForeignKey("categories.id"), nullable=True),
                      Column("sub_category_id", Integer,
                             ForeignKey("sub_categories.id"), nullable=True),
                      Column("alert_date", DateTime(timezone=True)))
```

curl:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/docs -d "category_id=1&sub_category_id=None&alert_date=None"
```

Here any of the parameter values are optional.

View:

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/docs', methods=['POST'])
def search_docs():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            doc_list = []
            category_id = request.form['category_id']
            sub_category_id = request.form['sub_category_id']
            custom_tag = request.form['custom_tag']
            alert_date = request.form['alert_date']

            f_dict = {
                'category_id': category_id,
                'sub_category_id': sub_category_id, 
                'alert_date': alert_date
                }
            for f in f_dict:
                if f_dict[f] == "None":
                    f_dict[f] = None

            s = select([docs]).\
                where(
                and_(
                     docs.c.category_id == category_id,
                     docs.c.sub_category_id == sub_category_id,
                     docs.c.alert_date == alert_date
                     )
                )
            print str(s)
            rs = conn.execute(s)
            for r in rs:
                doc_list.append(dict(r))

            return jsonify({'doc_list': doc_list}), 200
```

I have deleted some of the attributes as I was just trying out. Please revert as to how the query can be generated. I have many attribute values to consider in the query. Using flask 0.10, sqlalchemy core, python 2.7

On executing the above, the data is not consistently stored in the table. Sometimes it stores the record, but many times it throws up http 400 status code. How do I compare the sub_category_id to Null value which is optional?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'how the query can be generate', from your example you are already creating a SELECT query and executing it.  Do you mean seeing the raw SQL?

Comment: @WarrenSpencer I have edited comments  to above query. I just want the sql to be executing each time without http status code 400

Comment: @WarrenSpencer, rectified 400 status, by adding exactly same number of parameters in the curl command as in the dict being passed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want to conditionally build your where clause based on whether the value given for any filter is `None`. Does something like this work for you?:

```
conditions = []
if category_id is not None:
    conditions.append(docs.c.category_id == category_id)
if sub_category_id is not None:
    conditions.append(docs.c.sub_category_id == sub_category_id)
if alert_date is not None:
    conditions.append(docs.c.alert_date == alert_date)

s = select([docs]).where(and_(*conditions))
```

To ensure you have `None` values for the filters you wish to exclude, you could exclude them from the `curl` command line:

```
-d "category_id=1&sub_category_id=None&alert_date=None"
```

becomes:

```
-d "category_id=1"
```

Then in the Python script, you could use `get` whose default return value is `None`:

```
category_id = request.form.get('category_id')
sub_category_id = request.form.get('sub_category_id')
...
```

Another alternative is to use empty strings to indicate an excluded filter, which might be easier to pass around.

Comment: problem is when passed with a POST request, the values 'None' are stored as unicode, hence attribute values need to be compared like: if request.form['category_id']  == 'None':  then request.form['category_id']  = None  in the view. IS there a better method?

Comment: Could you simply not pass the excluded items when using curl, then use `request.form.get("category_id")`, which would return a real None?

Comment: How exactly in curl?

Comment: Edited my answer to include `curl` usage.

Comment: I get this error when I execute this: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'list'> instead. I used the *list. Was there an update?